# PHP shell_exec is not working. How to fix?

Tags: php, shell-exec

Im trying to make a page on linux server and i will use some shell command in php

But there are some problems with my code, Shell command is not working

My web php is here

```
<?php

$list = shell_exec("ls");
echo $list;

$remove = shell_exec("rm -rf testFolder");
echo $remove;

?>
```

Thats all, list command is working on php but remove command is not working.

Also it's working from terminal well even `safe_mode` is off

Do you know about this problem? (PHP version is 5.4 and i checked all config)

Comment: What user is php running as? What owner and permissions does testFolder have?

Comment: I hope you're paying someone for extended PHP support, because [PHP 5.4 last had an official security patch nearly eight years ago](https://www.php.net/eol.php).

Comment: When diagnosing things like this, `echo` can hide things, you might want to try `var_dump` or similar

Comment: Why don't you just use the php functions `scandir` and `unlink` (c.f.: https://www.php.net/manual/de/ref.dir.php)

Comment: You fix this error just lire any other: get the **error message** that explains the problem, and then act accordingly

Comment: Finally i solved this issue
You can fix like bellow

chcon -R -t httpd_sys_rw_content_t [folder]

Answer (score -1):

You have to change the file permission before removing files. Also set the full file or directory path.

```
<?php
$result = '';
$remove = realpath("/myproject/testFolder");
chmod($remove, 0777); //make sure I can handle the file
if(file_exists($remove)){ //Make sure that the file exists
    $result = shell_exec("rm -rf $remove");
}
var_dump($result);
?>
```

Comment: fyi, chmod makes no sense in this context. if you can change permissions then you can delete as well

Comment: Lets say i want to change file permission at run time at that time it works, or am i wrong @YourCommonSense

Comment: The file permission was 777 but it didnt work